# Как узнать номер самого большого кластера?

Tags: python, pandas

Я не понимаю, как вывести номер самого большого кластера. Есть столбец в датафрейме, где каждой строчке соответствует номер какого-то кластера, всего кластеров 10, их номера с 0-9, я могу посчитать количество раз сколько встречается каждый кластер, но я не знаю, как вывести номер кластера, который чаще всего встречается

Вот мой код:

```
print(df)
ser=df.groupby('cluster').size() # считаем сколько раз встречается каждый кластер

print(type(ser))

m=ser[df_2==ser.max()] #строка с самым часто встречающимся кластером
print(m)
```

[image: Вот данные, которые я могу вывести]

Comment: Используйте [.mode()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mode.html) или [.value_counts()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html)

Answer (score 5):

Не совсем ясно, чего вы хотите, потому я приведу больше возможностей.

В качестве примера я буду пользоваться таким датафреймом:

```
 >>> df
```

> ```
>        R    G    B  cluster
>  0   116  116  116        7
>  1     2    2    2        5
>  2   162  162  162        8
>  3   106  106  106        4
>  4    94   94   94        6
>  5   206  206  206        7
>  6   135  135  135        7
>  7     8    8    8        8
>  8   182  182  182        8
>  9   213  213  213        4
>  10   14   14   14        9
>  11  183  183  183        9
> ```

Когда вы хотите получить **номер кластера, который чаще всего встречается**
(таких номеров может быть больше):

```
 >>> df.cluster.mode().tolist()
```

> ```
>  [7, 8]
> ```

Когда вы хотите получить **их количество**:

```
 >>> df.cluster.mode().count()
```

> ```
>  2
> ```

Koгда вы хотите получить **все строки с такими кластерaми**:

```
 >>> df[df.cluster.isin(df.cluster.mode())]
```

> ```
>       R    G    B  cluster
>  0  116  116  116        7
>  2  162  162  162        8
>  5  206  206  206        7
>  6  135  135  135        7
>  7    8    8    8        8
>  8  182  182  182        8
> ```

Когда вы хотите получить **количество таких строк**:

```
>>> len(df[df.cluster.isin(df.cluster.mode())])
```

> ```
> 6
> ```

или

```
>>> df[df.cluster.isin(df.cluster.mode())].shape[0]
```

> ```
> 6
> ```

Когда вы хотите получить, **сколько раз встречается каждый кластер**:

```
>>> df.cluster.value_counts()
```

> ```
>  cluster
>  7    3
>  8    3
>  4    2
>  9    2
>  5    1
>  6    1
>  Name: count, dtype: int64
> ```

Когда вы хотите получить **максимальное количество совпадений**:

```
>>> df.cluster.value_counts().max()
```

> ```
> 3
> ```

или

```
>>> df.cluster.value_counts().iloc[0]
```

> ```
> 3
> ```

Comment: Какой обстоятельный ответ )